# Need to get mouse events inside webview Win 10 UWP

Tags: c#, events, webview, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am creating a win 10 UWP application.

```
<Grid>
<WebView x:Name="WebViewElm"/>
</Grid>
```

I have added a webview in it and I need to get the mouse right click and drag drop events for the webview element. But now it is taking the events for the browser. How I can handle the input events in the webview

Comment: WebView doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement, such as KeyDown, KeyUp, and PointerPressed. A common workaround is to use [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) with the JavaScript **eval** function to use the HTML event handlers, and to use **window.external.notify** from the HTML event handler to notify the application using [WebView.ScriptNotify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx).

Comment: I can try to add some more information later, but here is nice example: [How to intercept JavaScript alert in WebView in universal Windows apps](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-intercept-854d33da)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample of how to drag element from XAML to WebView. It's not complete solution, but might be helpful for you.

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView DefaultBackgroundColor="LightGray" Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html" PointerReleased="WebViewElm_PointerReleased" Width="300" Height="300" x:Name="WebViewElm"></WebView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtZiel" DragOver="txtZiel_DragOver" PointerReleased="txtZiel_PointerReleased" >2</TextBlock>       
    </StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
    private async void WebViewElm_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      await WebViewElm.InvokeScriptAsync("callFromExternal", new string[] { txtZiel.Text });
    }

    private async void WebViewElm_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await WebViewElm.InvokeScriptAsync("LoadingFinished", null);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<p id="txtClick">1</p>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function callFromExternal(somedrag) {    
        document.getElementById("txtClick").innerHTML = somedrag;
    }
```

The only thing you need is to check is mouse over paragraph element in your JavaScript code.

If you want to check events inside JavaScript code you can add **NavigationCompleted="WebViewElm_NavigationCompleted"** and **ScriptNotify="WebViewWithJSInjection_ScriptNotify"** attributes to your WebView and C# events

```
private async void WebViewElm_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        await WebViewElm.InvokeScriptAsync("LoadingFinished", null);
    }

   private void WebViewWithJSInjection_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
       // here in e.Value you can get string with document.getElementById("txtClick").innerHTML
    }
```

In JavaScript add functions:

```
    function LoadingFinished() 
    {
      document.getElementById('txtClick').addEventListener("mousedown", callExternal);
    }

    function callExternal()
    {
      window.external.notify(document.getElementById("txtClick").innerHTML);
    }
```