# Detecting idle user in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I would like to know **when the user is idle** to perform an action, so I decided that a good start would be to attach to the `PointerMoved` event in my `Page`. Every time the mouse cursor is moved, the counter is reset.

The problem is that my `Page` contains a `WebView` control that shows a website. It covers almost the whole part of the screen. I have observed that when I move the mouse cursor, the `PointerMoved` event isn't raised when it's over the `WebView`.

But it's even worse: the same happens when I add a handler to `myWebView.PointerMoved`. It doesn't raise any event!

Maybe I'm doing it wrong. 
What can I do to detect when the user is idle? Am I using the wrong method?

Comment: Do you want to only get time they are idle in just your program (such as if they minimized it and went to youtube for an hour) or do you want the time the user is idle from the computer (like they got up and stopped using the computer for an hour)

Comment: It's a kiosk mode application. I imagine it would be enough to know when the user is idle while my Page is being active. I doesn't have to be a perfect timing. The requisite is that, after some minutes, if the user doesn't produce any input it my Page, it will go back to Home (another Page).

Comment: Well webview does not support `PointerMoved` according to the docs, there is also a workaround in mentioned in the docs. Look at the remarks section. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx

Comment: @Jacobr365 it looks like a bad hack. Do you have an example about the invocation using the external script thingy? Thanks

Comment: I do not personally have an example. But google turns up a few with some looking. This isn't exactly what you want but should give you the basic idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155970/need-to-get-mouse-events-inside-webview-win-10-uwp

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it even via the CoreWindow object and it's PointerMoved event but even that one isn't fired with the webview.

Maybe background task with single proces model can let you accomplise your scenario?

The background task model contains triggers for userpresent and useraway:

```
new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserPresent, false);
new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.UserAway, false);
```

And with the single proces model you can make sure your app getting called and not a background task in an other proces: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/07/background-activity-with-the-single-process-model

Comment: OK, I'm a bit lost. Does it mean that I should create a background task to detect if the user is there? Supposing that I can create it correctly, how can I raise an event in the main application when the background one detects this condition (user is away)?

Comment: with the single process model it wont be called in a background process but just in your app process. It will call OnBackgroundActivated in your app.xaml.cs. from there you can push it to your UI if keep a reference to your rootframe for example

Comment: Can you show us some code? The reads are too broad. You know, it's better to learn by doing :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: give me some minutes. testing it right now; thing i don't like is that you dont have control about the definition of user beeing away / present. RIght now waiting till windows trigger the task

Comment: I finally got to try your application. Do you know how much time should I wait for the trigger to fire?